# App crashes on Nexus 4(4.4.4) due to background image

Tags: android, xml, nexus-4

I have set background image to root layout. This works fine for nexus 5(5.0.1) and nexus 5x(6.0.1).
But on nexus 4(4.4.4) app crash and gives following errors

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error
>   inflating class 
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.mobifilia.monitormymortgage.Fragments.HelpScreenFirstFragment.onCreateView(HelpScreenFirstFragment.java:38)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)

This is xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/backgraound">


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
       // other view
     </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

if i remove the background image from xml this works on nexus 4 also.
How can I solve this issue?? Thanks in advance

Comment: What _@drawable/backgraound_ contains?

Comment: @piyush this is background image with resolution 320*586 and 343.69 kb size.

Comment: In which drawable folder you have put the images ? Is this drawable-v21 ?

Comment: @ preetika kaur yes it is in drawable-v21

Comment: That is why it is woking in 5.0 and above. Put the images in drawable folder and check now.

Comment: Drawable-v21 means that file is available only for android api level 21 and higher. Android 4.4.4 is api level 19, therefore file is not available.

Comment: Put image in _drawable_ folder simply

Comment: @preetika kaur , marius kaunietis,piyush  thank you very much its working..

Comment: @preetika kaur can you please post this is as answer.

Comment: @Sangram yes sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have put images in **drawable-v21** folder which refers to Api **level 21 and above**. These folders are specific for **Lolipop** and **post Lolipop** version. That is why it is not working in Kitkat or more lower versions. Put your images in **drawable** folder so that all api versions can access this. 
Happy to help...

Answer (score 1):

Just put your image in the drawable folder. drawable -v21 is for android versions>19. Because if this in android 4.4 (api 19), its not able to fetch the image, and it may be throwing the error